# Using if/else by checking page URL

Tags: javascript, url

You can place the script where you want the content to be checked and loaded in your design.

- `urlCheck` is the name given to the function.  You can change it, and if you do, change all `urlCheck` references within the code.
- `window.location.href` returns the current address as *http://...*.  Use this to identify certain pages on which you want the content to be loaded.  Make as many `if`/`else` combinations as necessary.
- `document.write` builds the content to be loaded first.  Type with later in one unique line or create multiple `document.write`s for each line of your content.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function urlCheck() {
if(
window.location.href=="address to check"
)
{
/* some code to load */
}else{
document.write('<div>testing my super loaded div code sample</div>')
}
}
urlCheck() /* autoLoadFunction */
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I'd probably fix the indentation.

Comment: Add `//` at the beginning of the line with `<!--` or remove it from the line `//-->`

Comment: What is your question? What is the first paragraph supposed to mean?

Comment: Basic English lessons? Flaming aside, you do realize that we're here to do code review, and we do not accept anything that can't be answered? Because it seems like you want to use us as a blog, but we're not your personal blog. ... So, do you now have code which we can review?

Answer (score 5):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
```

The [`script` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html) does not have a property `language` anymore, that property is deprecated. You should use the property `type` instead. Also the correct value for that property would be `text/javascript`.

---

```
<!--
```

This is a relic from somewhere before all browsers could do JavaScript, please don't do it anymore.

---

```
function urlCheck() {
```

Nothing to say here. Except you should think about making it a habit to activate [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) by default.

---

```
if(
window.location.href=="address to check"
)
{
/* some code to load */
}else{
document.write('<div>testing my super loaded div code sample</div>')
}
}
```

- Your indentation and use of whitespace is completely broken, fix it.
- I've never seen a single if which was split over three lines, fix it.
- You should not use `==` unless you know what it is doing. `==` performs casting as necessary to compare two values, while `===` compares their type *and* value.
- I'm not a fan of creating HTML-elements in a string (`document.createElement()`), but for sure the opinions differ on this one vividly.

---

```
urlCheck() /* autoLoadFunction */
```

I suggest you either write your code *directly* and don't wrap it in a function (because that does nothing if you're going to directly run it after declaring) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href === "address to check") {
        // some code to load
    } else {
        document.write('<div>testing my super loaded div code sample</div>')
    }
</script>
```

Or run your code when the document is ready, by putting it at the end of the page (or use a framework which supports something like `$(document).ready()`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    urlCheck();
</script>
```

---

```
//-->
```

As I already said, that's a relic, stop doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
if(window.location.pathname === '/about'){
  //this is JavaScript for the about page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All above answers works, but we can also use Regular expressions

```
if (/StringtoCheck/.test(window.location.href))
{
 //yes it contains
}
```

Regex might help when conditions are a little bit tricky. Source: [How to check if url contains a sub-string using jQuery or javascript?](https://qawithexperts.com/questions/159/how-to-check)

OR you can simply use

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("YourStringToCheck") != -1){
   //string found code here
}
```